# Filter Get Request in Java

Tags: java, http, javafx, httprequest

I was wondering about sending a get request by parameter. For example, I have a JavaFX application and API written in Spring Boot. I want to send a get request from my application to the API, but I don't need all the data from the server. I need only data that answers to my criteria. I mean Date, which should belong to this year, and other criteria. Is it possible to do it? If yes, how? 
I know only a simple way to send a get request:

```
@GetMapping
public  ResponseEntity<List<DepartureDto>> getAll()
{
    List<DepartureDto> list = departureService.getAll();
    return ResponseEntity.ok(list);
}
```

Comment: That's why you use queries.